# Is there a way to stop the Geth console from printing syncing information?

Tags: go-ethereum

Is there a way to stop the Geth console from printing syncing information?

I start Geth with `geth console`.

Actually, I do not want to see all that syncing information constantly. Can I turn it off somehow without using geth attach?

Comment: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/javascript-console

Answer (score 19):

Yes you can do that. Take a look at [LOGGING AND DEBUGGING OPTIONS](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options#command-line-options)

Either you can set `geth --verbosity "0"` or you can log them into a file `geth --verbosity 5 console 2>> /path/to/logfile`

---

```
LOGGING AND DEBUGGING OPTIONS:
  --metrics         Enable metrics collection and reporting
  --verbosity "3"               Logging verbosity: 0-6 (0=silent, 1=error, 2=warn, 3=info, 4=core, 5=debug, 6=debug detail)
  --vmodule ""                  Per-module verbosity: comma-separated list of <module>=<level>, where <module> is file literal or a glog pattern
  --backtrace ":0"              Request a stack trace at a specific logging statement (e.g. "block.go:271")
  --pprof                       Enable the profiling server on localhost
  --pprofport "6060"            Profile server listening port
  --memprofilerate "524288" Turn on memory profiling with the given rate
  --blockprofilerate "0"    Turn on block profiling with the given rate
  --cpuprofile          Write CPU profile to the given file
  --trace           Write execution trace to the given file
```

Answer (score 15):

you can also change the verbosity in the client with `debug.verbosity(x)` where x is the level you want.

Comment: This is a valid point, if you're already in console. +1